# How can we make a ftp link open in windows explorer on Windows?

Tags: windows, hyperlink, ftp, explorer

Been trying to find a way to do this for a while.

Opening a link in an windows explorer window instead of a browser.

For example using this link : [ftp://username:pass@ftp.domain.com:80](ftp://username%3apass@ftp.domain.com:80)

And opening it in Windows Explorer.

Is it possible to dictate how windows should react when clicking on that link in a email ?

Comment: you can open it in browser like Internet Explorer or Chrome or anyother.

Comment: Yes, well actually it does that by default. I want to force it to open on windows explorer. In general people aren't really famillior with going on an FTP via Chrome or Internet Explorer. Instead i want to force it to open in a windows explorer as if they are browsing files on their computer.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/04/16/ftp-and-internet-explorer-what-to-do-what-to-do.aspx

Comment: Pretty cool, but i wont be asking each of my clients to manipulate their registry so they could open a FTP in windows explorer. Wont be really productive.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Fabian H!
Your solution works fine for me :-)

I made just a small change to your code, infact I wrote:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\explorer.exe" %1
```

Instead of:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe %1"
```

This second one didn't work for me :-(
But now I can finally enjoy using explorer.exe as the default FTP Client!!

**PS:**
Tested on WIndows 7

Answer (score 1):

Save these lines in a file with a file name ending *.reg* and double klick the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\ddeexec\Application]
@="Explorer"
```

Tested on WIndows 8.1 64bit.
Thanks to Perneel for his [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/04/16/ftp-and-internet-explorer-what-to-do-what-to-do.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows registry keys shown before didn't work for me, but this works:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\FTP
Use Web Based FTP = "yes"
```

Just change value to "no".

(Windows 7 Pro x64)

Answer (score 0):

I was fumbling around looking for how to do this and I ultimately decided to go with the "Add Network Location" wizard method as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/166469/how-to-make-shortcut-to-ftp-site-open-in-windows-explorer-not-ie) by "nhinkle".

However after doing so, I got a link that generated this shortcut:
ftp://MYFTP_LOGINID@FTPADDRESS/Some/Folder/Navigation/&Stuff/

More what it actually looks like:

ftp://123445_65432@78.13.223.184/root/main/servers/current/

Then was prompted for my login credentials, and thats it. Does not open in Chrome and I just did Send To > Desktop (shortcut) and moved that shortcut to the folder I wanted it in. Now I can open the FTP location from explorer by hitting the link instead of typing the address into the address bar, and it is not opening up in any internet browsers.

I only have one ftp account, dont know much about any background magic that the wizard may have done regarding registry/etc, and I feel like deleting the shortcut wont really undo any of that if it did happen, so if someone could test this and confirm whether or not it works, that'd be great.

Just my 2c :)

Answer (score 0):

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice
```

Check it out, i got the above answer working by deleting this entry

Answer (score -1):

For regularly used FTP sites, if you don't want to make registry edits, create a shortcut using the following format and your site will open in Windows Explorer.

%windir%\explorer.exe ftp://

Comment: Not working for me, it just opens a new Explorer window in My Documents.

Comment: Made my day. Works as charms. Thanx.

Comment: Working for me. Thanx